# Spring managed datasource connection to MS Sql server with Domain authentication

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring

I am getting an error when trying to create a datasource connection to MS SQL server using JTDS driver within my Spring Config.  I am using domain authentication from a non windows machine.

ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Spring-Datasource.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MS_SERVER/ms_db;domain=myDomain;integrated security=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="myUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
</bean>
```

I can create the connection manually and works perfect like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting Connection test");

    Connection connection;

    String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MS_SERVER/ms_db;domain=myDomain;integrated security=false";
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myUser","myPassword"));
        System.out.println("Connection successful");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If you try with `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MS_SERVER/ms_db;domain=myDomain;integrated security=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="myUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
</bean>
```

Dependency for DBCP:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html you need to pass useNTLMv2=true and domain=yourdomain.

Try this connection string

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MS_SERVER/ms_db;USENTLMV2=true;domain=myDomain"/>
    <property name="username" value="myUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
</bean>
```